# Where Can I Find a Novell NetWare Client for Ubuntu?

Tags: customization, login, client, novell-netware

I am trying to build a custom version of Ubuntu for my school and they seem to be using the Novell NetWare software (for Windows) so students can log-in to their accounts. I have tried using WebDav for the NetStorage server but that was unsuccessful. I have also tried a program called Novell Client for Linux but, it didn't fully support Ubuntu, it was butt ugly, the latest release was made in 2004.

If you guys could help me out on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "log-in to their accounts"? Are you referring only to NetStorage access, or are you trying to use Novell authentication to log in to the Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: What version of novell do you use? They work entirely differently.

Comment: @ændrük I am referring to the Novell authentication screen being implemented into Ubuntu. I figure I will just build a front-end for fusedav or ncpfs because I can't seem to find anything that does that.

Comment: @cstamas I am pretty sure it does not matter because we have Novell login clients ranging from versions 3-6 with the ability to login to the server without any problems.

Comment: that is true, but newer novell implements ldap which is way easier to use with linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to access NetStorage through WebDav in Ubuntu. You need to install the `fusedav` package and run something along the lines of:

```
fusedav -D -u username -p password_here http://server.com/oneNet/NetStorage /home/greg/netstorage
```

This isn't quite perfect, it occasionally goes a little buggy on me, but works for the most part. You might be interested to know I started [a bug about not being able to connect in Nautilus](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/649197) to NetStorage.

You may also be interested to know about `ncpfs` (see below & Google it), though I haven't used it myself.

> ncpfs allows you to mount volumes of NetWare servers under Linux and to print to NetWare print queues and spool NetWare print queues to the Linux printing system.

Comment: I've tried to use ncpfs but when it was mounted, it didn't show me MY files. It showed me a whole bunch of random stuff that didn't really make any sense. By the way, would you be able to direct me to a guide on how to set up ncpfs with the printers?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Novell CIFS.
This is a role which you have to install on the OES server.

Then Linux / Windows / Mac clients can access the share without a novell client but just SMB(CIFS).

Joeri

Answer (score -1):

If it allows mounting by webdav i would try to install davfs2-package and mount directly from Places->Connect to server... -> And from type choose WebDav.

If you put bookmark on it it stays on Placec bar on nautilus (file browser) so you can easily mount it again when need.

Comment: From my experience this doesn't work (see the bug report linked in my answer)

Comment: This dose not work, if I were able to, I would vote your comment as not useful because I clearly stated WebDav does not work.